# Open .html file through regedit

Tags: html, internet-explorer, regedit

I want to open my .html files in desktop through right click in IE. So I edit the regedit for IE in:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\test

so when I right click in IE window, it will has "test" menu, I want to open my test.html in my local desktop, so I put the value with:
C:/Users/test/Desktop/test.html

But when I click the menu, nothing happened. anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an underlying new key called "command".
And have to edit the value data to "C:/Users/test/Desktop/test.html".